# Does HP DL120 G9 support SSD?

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd, upgrade, hdd

I have some HP DL120 G9 with 4 x 3.5" HDDs that I want to upgrade to SSDs.

HP sells 3.5" SSDs, for example EAN 190017545103. Does the DL120 G9 support this drive or what options do I have?

The servers run MySql and the usage is mixed read/write.

Comment: Fast googling "HP DL120 G9" finds HP page https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04447806 which lists all parts that this server officially supports. First of all, you may install up to 4x3.84TB "LFF SSDs" (ordinary SSDs with adapter, I guess). There are many SSDs listed starting at page 21. It doesn't show EANs, only HPE Part Numbers (usually of the form NNNNNN-LNN), so I can't tell whether your SSDs are in the list. When buying upgrades, always refer to PNs. You may be required to install firmware updates onto your server to make it support newer parts.

Comment: However, for Mixed Use SSDs you will only be able to build at most 4x1.92TB configuration. And, if you need performance, use SAS drives; the interface is 4 times faster and it is really noticeable. I found one model for Mixed Use, 800GB one — 872378-B21

Comment: Thank you, @NikitaKipriyanov 
I could not find the drive in question in that document, hence the question, and this is the only SSD drive our supplier has. 
And according to our supplier, the server only has SATA so I totally missed that it supported SAS, as stated in the document.
But most of the data is loaded in MySql's InnoDb Buffer, so it should not make much of an difference, I think.

Comment: I am lazy reading it thoroughly; in principle there could be different drive backplanes, so it is possible for the server variant to only support SATA. Check your server; you can just look at physical socket on the backplane and see if it accepts SAS or not, also it could be inferred from the way the backplane itself connected to other parts. But proper HP parts supplier: 1) will show part numbers to be able to check compatibility, and 2) knows about HP servers enough so it at least might have hinted at possibility to have SAS and so on. I'd reather find another supplier.